# Xcode project setup

Tags: xcode, cloudkit, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I have just purchased my developer account to use CloudKit as well as other Apple APIs. Although there seems to be an issue. When logging into that account in an existing Xcode project, it gives me these erros:

> Cannot create a iOS App Development provisioning profile for "(*my-Bundle-identifier*)".
> Personal development teams, including "(*my-developer-account*)", do not support the iCloud capability.

> No profiles for '(*my-Bundle-identifier*)' were found
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '(*my-Bundle-identifier*)'.

Since I have no idea what a bundle identifier is, I assume that the problem lies there. Right now I have just been using a free "framer.ai" domain (technically not a real domain, but I don't own one), that is just a blank page.

It could also be that I've signed up less than 48 hours ago. Although my developer account seems to already be active, since I have access to the CloudKit console.

Comment: Have you logged in to developer.apple.com and gone to Certificates, IDs & Profiles to create a profile for your app? If it's all too confusing (and it can be), you can use tech support on your account and they will walk you through it.

Comment: No, I wasn't aware, that i had to do that. Thank you for your help